# MongoDB or Solr for document ingestion, storage, and faceted search?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, solr

I need to make an architectural decision here for a project I'm dealing with now.  Here are the requirements:

1. document ingestion (.doc, .pdf, .csv, maybe video)
2. actual document storage (I assume on the disk on the server with
   some reference to the file from the DB) - and certain fields that are searchable and facetable in the database??
3. full text document search
4. facetting (based on a selection of fields gathered from the document
   ingestion that may be different for each document - in other words
   may have 200 facets but only some apply to each document)

I'm using rails as a server and currently mySQL.  I believe I have at least 2 obvious choices here:

1. Solr; storing fields from documents in mySQL and using Sunspot gem for the Solr index and facet defining.  The benefits here seems to be fast search, faceting, document ingestion utilities.  I'm not sure about my issue with 200 (maybe more - really dynamically defined) facets.  Also, considering that the documents come in all shapes and sizes I wonder if a document storage mechanism would be better.
2. MongoDB; storing document contents in MongoDB using mongoid gem.  I'm not familiar with document ingestion utilities here and although there is an obvious win of document storage I believe that mongodb does a good job with full text search, but for faceting I need to use aggregation using multiple queries and that may be slow.

(I also know that I can possibly use Solr with MongoDB, but ... not sure about that).

Honestly I'm fairly new to both Solr and MongoDB and can use some advice here since I'm sure I'm missing some pros and cons.

Comment: I believe a storage network like S3 and solr might be best here

Comment: Current MongoDB production 2.2 does not have full text search, nor is it easy to build something efficient on top of it (not recommended). It's coming ... but, not ready for production. Even the facet search may be a problem depending on nature of the data.

Comment: Sammaye - thank you...for this app, the client is overly concerned with security so cloud storage is not an option (for them).  WiredPrairie, hmmm I guess I've been reading things wrong.  Obviously this would certainly put a nail in the coffin for mongodb.

Comment: Many providers, such as AWS (S3) support both private buckets and SSL connections, unless this is a governmental project that normally sufficies. However, considering that I would prolly house the documents themsleves in MongoDB and search with Solr, I am unsure how effective Solr will be with this kind of storage.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could use [elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org).

It's a search engine, using the same underlying lucene library that solr does, but everything you store in it is a JSON document.

Full text search, facetted search and filtering on lots of different attributes all work well. It does have some aggregation (histogram facets etc.) built in, although you should check these match your needs.

It's also very easy to build an elasticsearch cluster spanning several machines, depending on what your resiliency and throughput needs are.

There are several ruby bindings for it, including [tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) which is maintained by Karel Minařík, who works for elasticsearch.

Comment: Very interesting.  In reading all of the articles solr vs. elasticsearch I'm not sure I see big differences except that solr has (currently) more of a following.  Thoughts?

Comment: Last time i looked at the two solr 4 wasn't ready so some of this may be out of date, but at that point ES had better/easier distributed support, better child/parent and has more flexible storage (since you can store any json document you want, with nesting etc.). It's gathering momentum too, for example github and [stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) have moved over recently

Answer (score 2):

I have a good amount of experience with both MongoDB and Solr (though not related in any way).

Based off your needs, I recommend Solr.

I have worked on two different web apps with search issues and the first one, we switched from Oracle Text embedded in our transaction database to Solr.  Never looked back.

Even though MongoDB can probably be made to do what you're asking, I suspect you will spend a great deal of time making MongoDB behave the way you want, especially with faceting.  Mongo's aggregation framework is relatively new.

You said that you will need to run multiple queries for the facets.  I hope that isn't one query per distinct value, like for all categories, count the number of products in each category.  That may work fine on day one with development data, but wait until you get 10,000 products and 500 categories and 50 users searching concurrently.  Then you have 50 users concurrently running 500 queries against the same data.  You'll wind up needing to cache it.

Solr already does all this for you.  It is designed with these use cases in mind and handles faceting extremely well without you having to run N + 1 queries.  Solr also provides the necessary caching to avoid frequent disk I/O.  Solr is highly configurable.  You can tune your cache sizes, schema, analyzers, etc. without refactoring code.

Where I would recommend using MongoDB for search, for example, is when your needs are incredibly small and unlikely to change heavily.  For example, if you want a prefix search for, say, type-ahead, you could simply add a searchTokens field to each document and do the analysis yourself.

If searching the set of users, each user could look like:

```
{
  userId: 'x',
  firstName: 'Brandon',
  lastName: 'Ramirez',
  searchTokens: [
    'b',
    'br',
    'bra',
    'bran',
    'brand',
    'brando',
    'brandon',
    'r',
    'ra',
    'ram',
    'rami',
    'ramir',
    'ramire',
    'ramirez'
  ]
}
```

I have used that technique with MongoDB to avoid the complexity of Solr.  But that is all I needed.  It was for type-ahead, so I didn't need faceting nor did I need a dynamic set of filterable fields nor did I need relevance scoring.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It seems like Solr (w/mysql) is the way to go since I will have lots of documents and lots of searching/faceting with various levels of complexity.